# multiple conditions to Show input field only if a specific option is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I need that, at the beginning, only the following select form is displayed:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control tagging tagging_gouvernorat" onchange="yesnoCheck()">
             <option disabled selected>Etat</option>
             <option id="noCheck" value="actif">Actif</option>
             <option id="yesCheck1" value="loue">Loué</option>
             <option id="yesCheck2" value="vendu">Vendu</option>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, if `<option id="noCheck" value="actif">Actif</option>` is selected, no fields are displayed.
the other fields are displayed only if one of these options is selected:

```
<option id="yesCheck1" value="loue">Loué</option>
<option id="yesCheck2" value="vendu">Vendu</option>
```

but I don't know how to do ?

here is my html and javascript

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById("yesCheck1").selected) {
    document.getElementById("ifYes1").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ifYes1").style.display = "none";
  }
  if (document.getElementById("yesCheck2").selected) {
    document.getElementById("ifYes2").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ifYes2").style.display = "none";
  }
}


function yesnoCheck1() {
  if (document.getElementById("agence").selected) {
    document.getElementById("vagence").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("vagence").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 layout-spacing">
  <form id="social" class="section social">
    <div class="info">
      <h5 class="">Situation actuelle du Bien</h5>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11 mx-auto">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control tagging tagging_gouvernorat" onchange="yesnoCheck()">
                  <option disabled selected>Etat</option>
                  <option id="noCheck" value="actif">Actif</option>
                  <option id="yesCheck1" value="loue">Loué</option>
                  <option id="yesCheck2" value="vendu">Vendu</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="ifYes1" style="display: none;">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input id="basicFlatpickr" value="Date de la fin de contrat" class="form-control flatpickr flatpickr-input active" type="text" placeholder="Date de la fin du contrat" id="df" name="df">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="ifYes2" style="display: none;">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input id="basicFlatpickr" value="Date de la vente" class="form-control flatpickr flatpickr-input active" type="text" placeholder="Date de la vente">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="prix">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" id="prix" placeholder="Prix final" name="price">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="how">
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="how" onchange="yesnoCheck1()">
                  <option disabled selected value="comment">Comment ?</option>
                  <option id="seul" value="seul">Seul</option>
                  <option id="ag" value="viaagence">Via une agence</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="vagence" style="display: none;">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" id="vag" placeholder="Agence" value="" name="agence">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to explain in more detail where you are having problems

Comment: Initially, only the select menu is displayed: if no option is selected, there is no need to display any other field. also, if <option id="noCheck" value="actif">Actif</option> is selected, no fields should be displayed. the other fields are displayed only if options "loue" or "vendu" are selected.